# Set number of axis ticks with Julia Plots

Tags: julia

Is there a way to set the number of ticks that should be showing on each axis when using plotly with Plots.jl?

```
using Plots
plotly()
plot([1:10], [1:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `xticks` and/or `yticks` and a range

```
julia> using Plots

julia> plotly()

julia> plot([1:10], [1:10], xticks = 0:0.5:10, yticks = 0:0.5:10)
```

[image: julia plot]

Comment: is there a way to set total number of ticks regardless of zoom?

Comment: Zooming doesn't change the number of ticks in this case. Do you want to change them based on zoom?

Comment: Thats what im targeting.  A constant number of ticks in view.

Comment: You can set `ticks = :native` to get that, e.g `plot([1:10], [1:10], ticks = :native)`. But that leaves setting the total number up to plotly.

Answer (score 1):

See https://plotly.com/julia/axes/ for a complete documentation.

Simply put, if you want to have a certain number of autoplaced ticks, the following parameter will do it for you (using 20 ticks as an example).

```
Layout(yaxis=attr(tickmode="auto",nticks=20))
```

If you want to specify starting tick, and distance, pass:

```
Layout(yaxis=attr(dtick=0.5, tick0=0.25))
```

And if you want to specify ticks, pass:

```
Layout(yaxis_tickvals=[5.1, 5.9, 6.3, 7.5])
```